# How to transform a Pandas DataFrame into the following display? (from horizontal to vertical; with repeating keys)

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {
    'Column 1': ['A', 'B'],
    'Column 2': ['a_base', 'b_base'],
    'Column 3': ['a_part', 'b_part']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Gives an output of:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 
A        | a_base   | a_part   
B        | b_base   | b_part
```

How can I get the following:

```
New Column 1 | New Column 2 
A            | a_base       
A            | a_part       
B            | b_part       
B            | b_part
```

Comment: Did you try melt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) columns 2 and 3 into a new column, then select and sort by the columns you want to keep.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Column 1': ['A', 'B'],
    'Column 2': ['a_base', 'b_base'],
    'Column 3': ['a_part', 'b_part']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['Column 1'], value_vars=['Column 2', 'Column 3'], value_name='New Column 2')
df2 = df2[['Column 1', 'New Column 2']].sort_values(by='Column 1')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  Column 1 New Column 2
0        A       a_base
2        A       a_part
1        B       b_base
3        B       b_part
```

Comment: Thank You @Bill the Lizard! This works perfectly!  I am solving a real-life problem at work that involves our company products, base models, and parts.  This "mini-problem" and solution is directly translatable to my actual work problem.  Thanks!